# Code Injection attack in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a software to detect threats in code and it found a issue in the Jquery-1.2.6.js file. The issue is basically in this statement `data = eval("(" + data + ")");` which creates the data object like `data = xml ? xhr.responseXML : xhr.responseText;`.

I cannot change the Jquery version to a newer one so will have to work on this itself. I know this is not a code functionality issue but a security issue. Can someone provide any idea on how can I safely resolve this or is this not exactly an issue.

```
httpData: function( xhr, type, filter ) {
        var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type"),
            xml = type == "xml" || !type && ct && ct.indexOf("xml") >= 0,
            data = xml ? xhr.responseXML : xhr.responseText;

        if ( xml && data.documentElement.tagName == "parsererror" )
            throw "parsererror";

        // Allow a pre-filtering function to sanitize the response
        if( filter )
            data = filter( data, type );

        // If the type is "script", eval it in global context
        if ( type == "script" )
            jQuery.globalEval( data );

        // Get the JavaScript object, if JSON is used.
        if ( type == "json" )
            data = eval("(" + data + ")");

        return data;
    },
```

Comment: So...you can edit the file but can't replace it with a new version?

Comment: Transport as text type, then manually `JSON.parse`. If you can edit the library, change into `data = JSON.parse(data)`. This will not work on old browsers unless you also load the json3 library or something similar.

Comment: Changing would be a very long process at this client so modification would be preferred.

Comment: Just so you know, newer versions of jQuery will have already switched from `eval()` to the safer `JSON.parse()`.  jQuery v1.2.6 is really, really old so at some point, you should find it better to switch to a newer version that try to discover and reinvent all the improvements that have already been done.  I know there are times to do that switch and times not to, but it should be part of a plan for at least the mid term future.

Comment: Is it company policy preventing you from upgrading to a newer version or fears about browser compatibility?

Comment: Notice that this is only a security issue if you are loading JSON data from untrusted sources. Do you?